# Microsoft SQL query dilemma

Tags: sql-server

I have 4 tables:

```
tblWorkArea (*WA, WA.Description, Unitcode*)
tblWAFileNumber (*WA, FNo, Fno.Description*)
tblElement (*WA, FNo, Tasklist, Task, Element, Code*)
tblMiscValues (*WA, FNo, FieldLabel, Datavalue*).
```

I need to pull a report from these four tables joining on the WA, FNo fields

(common in all tables)that contains the following columns:

(WA, WA.Description, FNo, Fno.Desciption, Tasklist, Task, Element, Code, Datavalue)- where Unitcod='pq' and FieldLabel='xyz' and Datavalue should not be null.

I tried with a combination of joins but its still not pulling the report that I require somehow and pulling duplicate records.

FROM Comments: this is the current query:

```
select e.WA, w.description as WorkArea_Description
     , e.FNo
     , f.description as FileNumber_Description
     , e.tasklist
     , e.task
     , element
     , code
     , datavalue as Partnumber 
from tblElement e 
join tblworkarea w on e.WA=w.WA and 
join tblWAFileNumber f on e.WA=f.WA and e.Fno=f.FNo and 
join tblMiscValues m on e.WA=m.WA and e.FNo=m.FNo 
where UnitCode='pq' FieldLabel='xyz' 
  and DataValue not in ('Null','')
```

Comment: Post your current query so we can help you.

Comment: This is MySQL or sql-server?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need more details to be able to help. Here is a great place to start. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It's hard to find what's wrong with a query when you don't post that query.

Comment: Show sample data and desired results as well as posting any and all queries you've attempted.

Comment: For duplicates, we won't able to help you, either providing relationship between tables, 1 to 1, 1 to many or show some data.

Comment: This is the query right now I am working on , but I am not sure if this is correct:

select e.WA, w.description as WorkArea_Description, e.FNo, f.description as FileNumber_Description, e.tasklist, e.task, element, code, datavalue as Partnumber

from tblElement e join tblworkarea w on e.WA=w.WA

and join tblWAFileNumber f on e.WA=f.WA and e.Fno=f.FNo

and join tblMiscValues m on e.WA=m.WA and e.FNo=m.FNo

where UnitCode='pq' FieldLabel='xyz' and DataValue not in ('Null','')

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Also can I use 'USING' in this scenario?? I tried with the 'Using' keyword as well but the query executed with errors.

Comment: @Juby at first glance, the `and`s between the joins are not needed unless you're missing additional join critiera, and you're missing an and in the where clause between `UnitCode='pq' FieldLabel='xyz'`  1st join appears to be missing e.Fno=w.FNo .  Lastly, does dataValue really have 'NULL' string stored in the data?

Comment: w doesn't have the field FNo .. so it rules the join on e.FNo=w.FNo out. And yes datavalue does have null value for a lot of records so that filter is critical here. Thanks for the response @xQbert :)

Answer (score 1):

you could use inner join if you need only matching keys

```
select *
from tblWAFileNumber t1
inner join tblElement t2 on t1.WA = t2.WA and t1.FNo = t2.FNo
inner join tblMiscValues t3 on t1.WA = t3.WA and t1.FNo = t3.FNo
inner join tblWorkArea t4 on t1.WA = t4.WA
where t4.Unitcode = 'pq'
and t3.FieldLabel='xyz'
and t3.Datavalue is not null
```

or use left join  if you need also not matching keys related rows

```
select *
from tblWAFileNumber t1
left join tblElement t2 on t1.WA = t2.WA and t1.FNo = t2.FNo
left join tblMiscValues t3 on t1.WA = t3.WA and t1.FNo = t3.FNo 
    and  t3.FieldLabel='xyz' and t3.Datavalue is not null 
left  join tblWorkArea t4 on t1.WA = t4.WA and t4.Unitcode = 'pq'
```

Comment: This answer is not correct, LEFT JOIN with WHERE clause, it is same as INNER JOIN. And it doesn't address the issue with duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I tried running both of these queries but unfortunately both of them are pulling out zero records. :(

Answer (score 0):

Just addressing the syntax errors presented (reformatted so I could more quickly discern syntax issues.)

```
SELECT e.WA, w.description as WorkArea_Description
     , e.FNo
     , f.description as FileNumber_Description
     , e.tasklist
     , e.task
     , element
     , code
     , datavalue as Partnumber 
FROM tblElement e 
INNER JOIN tblworkarea w  
   on e.WA=w.WA 
-- and  had an extra and.
INNER JOIN tblWAFileNumber f 
   on e.WA=f.WA 
  and e.Fno=f.FNo --had an extra and here.
INNER JOIN tblMiscValues m 
   on e.WA=m.WA 
  and e.FNo=m.FNo 
WHERE UnitCode='pq' 
  and FieldLabel='xyz' --missing the leading and here.
  and DataValue not in ('Null','') --this just seems odd to check for null string and empty set.. I'd need to see sample data containing null string and empty set to understand what you're trying to do here.
--and DateValue <> ''  --maybe this 
--and Datevalue is not null --with this instead?
```

When you have multiple tables involved, it is wise to fully qualify the source tables for the elements as we don't know what values come from which tables.  So element, code, datevalue need to define the source tables.in the select, and in the where clause all values need to be fully qualified.

Comment: Iam really sorry but Iam not able to add the sample data here but the Datavalue field does contain values as (Null, ' ', *, -.. etc) . The report pulled however should eliminate all these garbage values and should include only those records with well defined values. An example Datavalue is 'DQ01054'. So I need to eliminate everything else that doesn't come in this format for the Datavalue field.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Should DataValue allays be 7 characters?  as it stands not enough information exists on what is construed as bad data.  NULL and 'NULL' and '' are not the same thing.  NULL is the absense of any data.  '' is empty set and 'NULL' is a string so maybe `and len(trim(datevalue))>7` or length instead of len depending on db.

Comment: Thank you so much.. will try using this.. :)